# How to remove category from URL?

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, seo

I have a little problem - I want to remove categories and submenus from URL in Joomla 3.9.3. Of course, I did basic things like removing ID from URLs, but removing category is like a milestone for me. For example, now it's like that:

www.funnypage.com/main-menu-item/sub-menu/article

And I want archive something like this:

www.funnypage.com/article ,

but still using navigation like in this page: http://wisznice.work.mbnet.pl/o-gminie/historia/pamietniki

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

By default it is not possible, the structure of your menu sets the structure of your URL.

Some users enable the Plugin called **System - Redirect** and create some redirections in the Component wich is also called **[Redirects](https://docs.joomla.org/Help39:Components_Redirect_Manager)**, from something like:

***website.com/category/subcayegory/article*** to ***website.com/article***

But yes, this is a manual process one by one URL.

Another way to solve this is create just one main category, one main menu for your content,  but for the categories you can use a feature called **[tags](https://docs.joomla.org/Help39:Components_Tags_Manager_Options)** to group your content.

Answer (score 0):

Route 66 to date works in both joomla 3.10.8 and joomla 4.1.2.
The functions for joomla content are free.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to contribute to JSE.  The system has automatically flagged this answer as low-quality for its length.  If you are able, please [edit] your answer to be less of a vague advertisement for the extension by adding more detail about how the extension solves this specific question.  Please also register your account and take our [tour]. We look forward to seeing more contributions from you.